# Regex - Match character except lines that starts with a specific character

Tags: java, regex

I want to match **ONLY** with < except if line starts with #

example

```
aaaaa < aaaa true
#aaaa < aaaa false
aaaa < aaa < true
```

It must be **3** matches not **2**

Comment: From [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), `Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.` what did you try? Where did you fail soving it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be done with a variable-width negative lookbehind pattern, which unfortunately is supported by only a few regex engines not including Java's:

```
(?<!^#.*)<
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jcCGtZ/2

Comment: I explained wrong and editted post. Could you please look at it again?

Comment: I've updated my answer although it isn't meant for Java.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^[^#](?=.*<).*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iNanBB/2)

Comment: I explained wrong and editted post. Could you please look at it again?